# How to solve internal server error for next.js on stackblitz?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stackblitz

I'm trying to create a simple example for a problem I have in NextJS.

The problem is that it encountered an error, showed **Internal Server Error** and now I'm stuck at how to make it work.

I retried many times. But each time somewhere it encounters this error and never recovers.

Here's an example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-9zbx4x?file=cache.js

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

As it states on console error:

> Error: [BABEL] /home/projects/nextjs-9zbx4x/node_modules/next/dist/client/dev/amp-dev.js: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-macros'

You need to add `babel-plugin-macros` dependency in `dependencies` section of your `package.json` like this:

```
"babel-plugin-macros": "3.1.0",
```

You can take a look at [this forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-2jw2xt?file=package.json) for the live working update with `babel-plugin-macros` dependency.